# Dataview Item indexOf()

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have a dataview.dataview (list) which display my dataview.dataview.component.item.

These components are defined  like this :

```
this.removeAll();
var tag;
switch(record.get('strUIType'))
{
    case 'folder'   :
    {
        tag = Ext.create(APPNAME+'.view.folder_Tag');
        tag.getComponent('name_Label').setHtml(record.get('strName'));
        tag.getComponent('value_Label').setHtml(record.get('numValue'));
        break;
    }
    case 'numInput' :
    {
        tag = Ext.create(APPNAME+'.view.numInput_Tag')
        tag.getComponent('name_Label').setHtml(record.get('strName'));
        tag.getComponent('field').setValue(record.get('numValue'));
        break;
    }
    case 'slidInput':
    {
        tag = Ext.create(APPNAME+'.view.slidInput_Tag');
        tag.getComponent('name_Label').setHtml(record.get('strName'));
        tag.getComponent('value_Label').setHtml(record.get('numValue'));
        tag.getComponent('value_Slider').setValue(record.get('numValue'));
        break;
    }
    default :
    {
        break;
    }

}
this.add(tag);
```

Let's the case strUIType === 'numInput'.

I have a controller which listen to the Textfield inside every numInput_Tag view-element. 
I actually can get the value that was entered correctly.  What I would need to get that I haven't been able to is the index in the Dataview.dataview of the dataview....item that was modified.

Is there anyway from inside my numInput_Tag to retrieve the index of it? Or any other way that would work nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a global variable to the value of the
   `indexOf(list.lastFocused);`